# Solr - how to index entire csv as one document vs. treating each row as document

Tags: csv, indexing, solr, lucene, document

I would like to index a csv file.
Ex:

```
col1,col2
cat,dog
boy,girl
```

Normally, once indexed, Solr creates three documents, one for each row.
I would like to treat the whole document like its a .txt while keeping it as a csv.  So far I figure I should just read the contents into a txt file and just index that. I would like to avoid this if possible though, because I am using paths for the id field, and the whole reading into text, indexing, and setting id path to the original csv feels hacky.

Comment: If you just send it as text, what fields do you expect Solr to map content to? Do you want any field splitting at all?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just want the whole doc to be searchable based on its contents, no fields, except the file path are needed.

Comment: So, the coma-separation does not matter to you. Just everything, all lines, loaded together into one field with path in the second field? Then, you are not talking about a CSV file. You just want the whole file read as one text field, right?

Comment: Correct, all text in one field.  I am indexing a drive with many unstructured docs.  Ideally a program with crawl through the directories, indexing as it goes.  In this case a CSV file should be treated as one doc, not n X rows docs.  I realize a can extract the data as text into a .txt file, but I was wondering if there was just a way to have solr not treat a CSV how it usually does.

Comment: How are you indexing? If it is a custom program, it might just be easiest to load the file programmatically and construct a Solr document. Or is it bin/post with recursive directory crawl?